# Using Google Drive API/SDK to insert new folders and files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I would like to automate the following process using c#:
1. Take a file from a predefined folder
2. Upload said file to Google drive account folder, creating new folder if necessary
Determine permanent link of said folder
store said link in a database.
authorized gdrive users will click on the link to open file

can this be accomplished using the API or SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a .NET/C# SDK for working with Google APIs:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

And here is a specific example of using that SDK with the Google Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet